# Почему на теме WP не работает плагин jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

http://mihzas-portfolio123.000webhostapp.com/portfolio/
при нажиме на изображение нету эффекта пиробокса

в файле functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');<br/>
wp_enqueue_script('galery-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/piroBox.1_2.js', array('jquery'));
```

(лог и пасс от хостинга находится в первой ревизии вопроса)

Comment: Здесь не занимаются техподдержкой и ваши данные от хостинга не нужны. Постарайтесь лучше описать вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать ответ не прибегая к осмотру хостинга. См. [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) в справке.

Comment: А зачем в php тег <br/>?? Может в этом вопрос?

Comment: Нет это разметка в вопросе